# jQuery - Using .slideToggle and .animate simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a portion of jQuery that just doesn't seem to be working correctly. I have a link to click, [show/hide] which should slideToggle a div. At the same time, I want to animate it so that the page scrolls to the top of the div. It works when I put the `animate` function inside the `slideToggle` function, like [in this jfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YFR2e/2/).

However, this means that the div i want slides out, and *then* the page scrolls down. id like to set it up so that both happen simultatneously, which I tried to do in [this jfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/JzU5G/1/) but it simply doesn't work. I also tried doing the scroll animation first, then the slideToggle, which didn't work - is there a way to implement this also?? Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click_to_hide').click(function () {
        var visible = $('.hide_on_click').is(":visible");
        $('.hide_on_click').slideToggle(500);
        if (!visible) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.hide_on_click').offset().top
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/YFR2e/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click_to_hide').click(function () {
        $('.hide_on_click').slideToggle(500);
        if($('.hide_on_click').is(':visible')){
          $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.hide_on_click').offset().top
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

try to put it in the same function